# How to implement a Button, that Re-directs to another page?

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML5 coding and I am wondering how to implement a button on my landing page, which re-directs the visitor to another page.

Currently I am using the following HTML coding:

```
<section id="calltoaction_2">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="http://protec4kids.com/order">
      <center><button type="submit" class="button_2">Order Here Now</button></center>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

The problem is, that when I click the button, I am redirected to another page with the QUESTION MARK at the end of the URL. Which makes the website not appearing.

The second page is made up, in html and names 'order'.

Comment: you know that there is a tag call link (`a`) which already do this ? [to avoid the question mark make the method post as by default it's get]

Comment: Don't use the `<center>` element. It was deprecated ages ago and no longer exists

Comment: use an anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is just a simple link.

Just forget about your form, you don't need it. Form is use to send data through page, mailbox, database, that kind of stuff.

If you just want to redirect to another page try this :

```
<a href="http://protec4kids.com/order">Hey ! this is a link :D</a>
```

And forget this `<center><center>` that's deprecated :)

I Hope that I help you !